# How to run the Ruby on Rails rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, bash

I am trying to run the rake which is a ruby on rails based command, in a cron job, so I have written a bash script, and placed the bash script in the cron, but I am unable to do it.

This is the command which I have want to execute once the server boots up.

```
RAILS_ENV=production ruby script/delayed_job status
```

I bash script which is I have written which is not being executed

```
#!/bin/sh

export RAILS_ENV=production 
/usr/bin/ruby script/delayed_job start
```

Kindly help me out to solve this issue

Comment: Where didi you put the script? Did you restart crond afterwards?

Comment: You don't need to do that. The cron daemon will re read the file every  "tick".

Comment: I have placed the script the inside the root folder of the rails app, nope I have not restarted the crond, in dont think I need to restart the crond.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing a `cd /path/to/your/application` command?

```
export RAILS_ENV=production 
cd /path/to/your/application && /usr/bin/ruby script/delayed_job start
```

Comment: I have placed the bash script inside the root folder of the rails app it self.

Comment: In that case, what does your crontab read? Can you paste it here?

Comment: :here is the crontab  * * * * * bash /home/ec2-user/apps/st/rake_delayed_jobs.sh

Comment: You want it run *every second* ?

Comment: Also, bash does not automatically switch to working directory. You *still* need to `cd` to the working directory. For current directory, you can use **`.`**.